# Read a file during execution of C program and store all the items and their respective prices in an array of structure items

Tags: c

How can I solve this problem given to us in our lab test? I have tried manier times but failed. I have started learning C since 2 months.

*Q:
Read a file named food.txt during execution of your program to store all these items and their respective prices in an array of structure item.*

Note: '**struct item**' contains '**char name**' and '**int price**'.
Also, first line of food.txt gives number of entries.
(command:  ./a.out < food.txt).

Edit: This is my code. I can't find my mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>

//Defining the struct
typedef struct {
    char name[25];
    int price;
}item;

int main(){
    int n;  //Number of entries
    int i,j,k,flag;

    int temp[40];

    scanf("%d",&n);//first line gives number of entries as input

    item items[n]; //creating our items struct

    int c = getchar();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        items[i].price=0;
        for(j=0;;j++){  
            c=getchar();
            if(c<'0' || c>'9') items[i].name[j]=c; //If c is character, it store it in name
            if(c=='\n')break;  //If c is \n, it breaks from the loop and starts again with i++
            temp[j]=c;
        }

        for(j=0;;j++){  

            if(temp[j]>=0 && temp[j]<=9){
                items[i].price = (items[i].price)*10 + temp[j];
            }       
            else if(temp[j]=='\n')break;
        }   
}

    printf("\n.........................................\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d.  %s  %d  \n",i+1,items[i].name,items[i].price);
    }
}
```

*food.txt*

```
8

hot black tea 5

hot lemon tea 6

hot masala tea 7

hot milk tea 9

hot black coffee 7

hot milk coffee 10

finger potato 45

potato chips 35
```

Comment: Step 1: read in the file line by line and print out what you read. Take it one step at a time. Step 2, separate the data into name and price, just print them for now. And so on, but you have not asked a question.

Comment: So, please with what do you come up, for us to debug? ;)

Comment: _contains `char name`_: Hopefully not! A `char` can store a single character. To store a string, you need a bit more - either a `char name[???]` (where ??? stands for a sufficient number) or a `char *name` (where needed storage is allocated with `malloc()`). Please, don't forget that strings in C are terminated by a `'\0'` character which has to be considered in storage.

Comment: what i thought was to take first input 'n' which gives number of lines. Then I created a for loop which goes from 0 to n-1. Now I tried to store input in 'items.name' until the getchar() give value in a numerical format and then change input to be stored in 'items.price'. But that is not working properly. help!!

Comment: See, we are here to *help* you with *your* work. But if there isn't any, then please how to do this?

Comment: Do not try to tell us how your code would look in prose. Just start coding, fail and show us where, and tell us what exactly you do not understand. Also do not do this in comments, but using updates to your answer.

Comment: People who tried and failed did more then those who didn't even try.

Comment: sure alk, i have just started using stackoverflow and am still being used to it. thanks for your advice @alk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `fgets()` and `sscanf()` functions found in `stdio.h`. This gives the ability to scan the same line of input repeatedly when unexpected input arises, and is generally a better option than using `scanf()` alone.

In the code below, the `line[]` array is used to hold the contents of each line of input. This has been made large enough to hold any reasonably sized line, but [`fgets()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2) ensures that unexpected input will not cause a buffer overflow. More robust code would check for such large inputs anyway, which would cause problems with the remaining input. Note also that the `name[]` field of the `item` structure has been enlarged from 25 to 256; there is no reason to be stingy here.

The `fgets()` function is used to get the first line of input, and if no line is retrieved, or if the first line is non-numeric, an error message is printed to `stderr` and the program exits with a value of `-1`.

Then the `fgets()` function is used again in a loop to read lines of input which are parsed by `sscanf()`. Here a [scanset](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2) is used to scan the input `line[]` and assign to the `.name` field; it is assumed that the food name contains no numbers. Also note that the `.name` field will contain *any* non-numeric characters found before the first digit, so any spaces found before the price will be included in the `.name` string. These spaces could be trimmed, if desired. Before parsing with `sscanf()`, the code checks to see if the input `line[]` is blank, i.e., if the first character is a newline character; if so, the item counter `i` is decremented, and the loop is `continue`d, skipping any blank lines in the input.

Finally, the contents of the `items[]` array are displayed for verification.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct item {
    char name[256];
    int price;
};

int main(void)
{
    int num_entries;               // number of entries, not number of lines
    char line[512];                // storage for input lines

    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Empty input file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &num_entries) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Formatting error in first line\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct item items[num_entries];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Inconsistent file length\n");
            return -1;
        }

        // Do not count blank lines
        if (line[0] == '\n') {
            --i;
            continue;
        }

        // Assign to struct
        if (sscanf(line,
                   "%255[^0123456789]%d",
                   items[i].name, &items[i].price) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Formatting error in entry %d\n", i + 1);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // Display contents of array
    for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++) {
        printf("Item %d: %s, $%d\n", i + 1, items[i].name, items[i].price);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
>$ ./a.out < food.txt 
Item 1: hot black tea , $5
Item 2: hot lemon tea , $6
Item 3: hot masala tea , $7
Item 4: hot milk tea , $9
Item 5: hot black coffee , $7
Item 6: hot milk coffee , $10
Item 7: finger potato , $45
Item 8: potato chips , $35
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an minimal example for understanding how to approach this problem statement:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #define MAX 100

 struct node
 {
     char name[MAX];
     int  price;
 };

 int main(void)
 {
     int    inp;
     int    count_char=0;                         //COUNTS THE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS OF A NAME
     int    count_arr=0;                          //COUNTS THE NUMBER OF SEPARATE NAME-PRICE STRUCTURES USED
     struct node EMPTY={{'\0'},0};                //EMPTY STRUCTURE FOR DEFAULT INITIALIZATION
     struct node arr[]={[0 ... 99]=EMPTY};        //ARRAY OF STRUCTURES CONTANING 100 ELEMENTS
     int    temp_count=0;
     int    count_space=0;                        //COUNT NUMBER OF SPACES WITHIN THE STRING

     while((inp=getchar())!=EOF)
     {
         if(inp=='\n')
         {
             count_space=0;
             count_arr++;
             count_char=0;
             continue;
         }
         if((((inp>='A')&&(inp<='Z'))||((inp>='a')&&(inp<='z')))||(inp==' '))
         {
             if((count_char==0)&&(inp==' '))       //LEADING SPACE HANDLING
             {
                 continue;
             }
             if(inp==' ')                          //SPACE WITHIN STRINGS HANDLING
             {
                 ++count_space;
             }
             else
                 count_space=0;
             if(count_space>1)
                 continue;
             arr[count_arr].name[count_char++]=inp;
         }
         if((inp>='0')&&(inp<='9'))
         {
             arr[count_arr].price = (arr[count_arr].price)*10 + inp - '0';
         }
     }

     while(temp_count<count_arr)
     {
         printf("%s",arr[temp_count].name);
         printf("%d\n",arr[temp_count++].price);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

If the file contains:

**INPUT:**

```
3
xyz 123
    abc 89
lmn              tub    956
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
xyz 123
abc 89
lmn tub 956
```

**NOTE:** There can be tons of things done to streamline this example but this is only a minimal demo.

Comment: thanks so much for you time sir, but i am not able to clearly understand the functions like memset() and also we were asked to use 'stdio.h' only.

Comment: @AjayYadav You didn't mention it in the question, wait!

Comment: @AjayYadav Changed.

Answer (score -2):

*scnr*:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRING(x)

#define MAX_ITEM_NAME_LENGTH 100

typedef struct item_tag {
    char *name;
    int price;
} item_t;

item_t item_create()
{
    item_t new_item = { NULL, 0 };
    return new_item;
}

bool item_read(item_t *item)
{
    char name[MAX_ITEM_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    int price;

    if (scanf(" %" STRINGIFY(MAX_ITEM_NAME_LENGTH) "[^0-9]%d%*[\n]", name, &price) != 2)
        return false;

    size_t name_length = strlen(name);
    if (name_length && isspace((int)name[name_length - 1]))
        name[--name_length] = '\0';

    item->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    strcpy(item->name, name);
    item->price = price;
    return true;
}

void item_print(item_t *item, size_t longest_name_length)
{
    printf("%-*s %4d\n", (int)longest_name_length, item->name, item->price);
}

void item_destroy(item_t *item)
{
    free(item->name);
}

typedef struct products_list_tag {
    size_t size;
    item_t *items;
    size_t longest_name_length;
} products_list_t;

products_list_t products_list_create(void)
{
    products_list_t new_products_list = { 0, NULL, 0 };
    return new_products_list;
}

bool products_list_read(products_list_t *products_list)
{
    size_t num_items;
    if (scanf(" %zu%*[\n]", &num_items) != 1)
        return false;
    else if (!num_items)
        return true;

    item_t *new_items = calloc(num_items, sizeof *new_items);
    size_t num_valid_items = 0;
    size_t longest_name_length = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_items && !feof(stdin); ++i) {
        new_items[i] = item_create();
        if (!item_read(&new_items[i]))
            --i;
        else {
            ++num_valid_items;
            size_t name_length = strlen(new_items[i].name);
            if (longest_name_length < name_length)
                longest_name_length = name_length;
        }
    }

    if (num_valid_items != num_items) {
        free(new_items);
        return false;
    }

    new_items = realloc(new_items, num_valid_items * sizeof *new_items);
    products_list->items = new_items;
    products_list->size = num_valid_items;
    products_list->longest_name_length = longest_name_length;
    return true;
}

void products_list_print(products_list_t *products_list)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < products_list->size; ++i)
        item_print(&products_list->items[i], products_list->longest_name_length);
}

void products_list_destroy(products_list_t *products_list)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < products_list->size; ++i)
        item_destroy(&products_list->items[i]);

    free(products_list->items);
    products_list->size = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    products_list_t products = products_list_create();
    if (!products_list_read(&products)) {
        perror("Failed to read products list!\n\n");
        products_list_destroy(&products);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    products_list_print(&products);
    products_list_destroy(&products);
}
```

#### Update:

Just read about a stupid no-other-headers-than-`<stdio.h>` restriction in a comment on a temporarily deleted, now resored answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRING(x)

#define MAX_ITEM_NAME_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_PRODUCTS_LIST_ITEMS_COUNT 100


/* BEGIN stupid no-other-headers-than-<stdio.h> workaround */
#define MY_EXIT_FAILURE -1
#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef int my_bool;

size_t my_strlen(char const *str)
{
    char const *p = str;
    while (*p) ++p;
    return p - str;
}

char* my_strcpy(char *dst, char *src)
{
    char *p = dst;
    while (*dst++ = *src++);
    return p;
}
/* END stupid no-other-headers-than-<stdio.h> workaround */


typedef struct item_tag {
    char name[MAX_ITEM_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    int price;
} item_t;

my_bool item_read(item_t *item)
{
    char name[MAX_ITEM_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    int price;

    if (scanf(" %" STRINGIFY(MAX_ITEM_NAME_LENGTH) "[^0-9]%d%*[\n]", name, &price) != 2)
        return false;

    size_t name_length = my_strlen(name);
    if (name_length && name[name_length - 1] == ' ')
        name[--name_length] = '\0';

    my_strcpy(item->name, name);
    item->price = price;
    return true;
}

void item_print(item_t *item, size_t longest_name_length)
{
    printf("%-*s %4d\n", (int)longest_name_length, item->name, item->price);
}


typedef struct products_list_tag {
    size_t size;
    item_t items[MAX_PRODUCTS_LIST_ITEMS_COUNT];
    size_t longest_name_length;
} products_list_t;

products_list_t products_list_init(void)
{
    products_list_t new_products_list = { 0 };
    return new_products_list;
}

my_bool products_list_read(products_list_t *products_list)
{
    size_t num_items;
    if (scanf(" %zu%*[\n]", &num_items) != 1)
        return false;
    else if (!num_items)
        return true;

    size_t num_valid_items = 0;
    size_t longest_name_length = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_items && !feof(stdin); ++i) {
        if (!item_read(&products_list->items[i]))
            --i;
        else {
            ++num_valid_items;
            size_t name_length = my_strlen(products_list->items[i].name);
            if (longest_name_length < name_length)
                longest_name_length = name_length;
        }
    }

    if (num_valid_items != num_items)
        return false;

    products_list->size = num_valid_items;
    products_list->longest_name_length = longest_name_length;
    return true;
}

void products_list_print(products_list_t *products_list)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < products_list->size; ++i)
        item_print(&products_list->items[i], products_list->longest_name_length);
}


int main(void)
{
    products_list_t products = products_list_init();
    if (!products_list_read(&products)) {
        perror("Failed to read products list!\n\n");
        return MY_EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    products_list_print(&products, stdout);
}
```

#### Output:

```
hot black tea       5
hot lemon tea       6
hot masala tea      7
hot milk tea        9
hot black coffee    7
hot milk coffee    10
finger potato      45
potato chips       35
```

Comment: Why are you using `FILE *input_file`?

Comment: @infinite Missed that. Thanks for making me aware of. Changed the code.